# Ruby on Rails Google maps javascript api not working on heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, google-maps, heroku

So I used the google maps javacript api and it worked fine on localhost but didn't work at all on heroku

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBzNWjSdV5kTfGUZt-JU3HKI4liwN_u7nE&callback=initMap"></script>
```

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the error you get in the console?

Comment: @ZiyanJunaideen I'm basically using jquery locationpicker. $(...).locationpicker is not a function is the error I get in the console

Comment: Meaning your JS is not loaded. Is location picker included in the asset manifest (probably `application.js`)?

Comment: @ZiyanJunaideen Yup

Comment: Check dev tab in Chrome to make sure the script loads. If it does load, which is the likely scenario, you might be having JS run before it. For example you may have the JS code in `body` while the script loads in footer.

Comment: @ZiyanJunaideen I've tried everything and still cant find anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your assets are probably not precompiled by default. Here are the steps that should solve your problem:

First go to tou */config/environments/production.rb* file and make sure:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

and then run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Once that's done you should push all those compiled files to Heroku.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: nope that wasn't the issue. I'm basically using jquery locationpicker. $(...).locationpicker is not a function is the error I get in the console

Comment: btw doesn't heroku do that for you automatically.